# What is Salt's equivalent to Ansible's hostvars?

Tags: automation, ansible, salt-stack

I was trying to install salt master and salt minions using salt-ssh.

In that I need to put the proper configurations on the remote machines.
Both master and minions need the salt master's ip in the configuration file.
I have done this in ansible using

```
interface: {{  hostvars[groups['salt_master'][0]]['inventory_hostname'] }}
```

Is there a way to read the roster file? What is the salt way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to assign pillar variables for this.

cat `/srv/pillar/top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
    - master_vars
```

cat `/srv/pillar/master_vars.sls`:

```
master_ip: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then in your config file you'd have something like this:

```
interface: {{ pillar.get('master_ip') }}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is something that I was trying to avoid because I wanted to write the ip in only 1 place so that any change in the ip is easy to maintain.  Now I need to write it in atleast 2 places, in pillars and the roster file

Comment: Why do you need to write it in the roster file?